# Как, используя arecord (alsa), записать со всех каналов всех устройств?

Tags: c++, linux, c, terminal

Пытаюсь записать capture со всех каналов всех устройств (каждый канал в отдельный файл), используя `arecord`. Выполняю в консоли такую команду:

```
arecord -C -d 10 -D plughw:0,0 -c 2 -f cd --separate-channels c1.wav c2.wav
```

Вопрос: как задать перебор по всем девайсам и увеличить количество каналов, с которых можно читать? Сейчас больше двух каналов читать не дает.